# short to earth 120 v ac breaker

Tags: grounding

If a hot wire is shorted to earth i.e. the hot 120 v ac wire that comes out of a Ex. 20 amp breaker is directly connected (short) to a grounding rod, why wont the breaker trip.

Comment: If the grounding rod is part of the grounding electrode system, the breaker should trip.

Comment: watch this.                                                                               https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GI0Q9X2ih-U

Comment: That video is demonstrating exactly what everybody here is saying. If Grayfurnaceman's "earth ground" was bonded to the service neutral, the breaker should trip, because then he'd have an effective ground-fault current path.

Comment: @Tester101 Be that as it may you were the only one to explain it SIMPLY, so you answered the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not going to trip, because the contact resistance between the rod and the ground is too high, therefore the current will be low (Ohm's law). Despite what people may think, electricity is trying to find a way back to the **source**, not to the ground (earth).

When you connect the ungrounded hot conductor to the earth, electricity has to flow through the earth to find a way back to the source (the distribution transformer).  Since the ground rod has a high contact resistance with the earth, the current seen at the breaker is quite low. For the breaker to trip, the current has to be high enough for long enough. However, this type of fault will likely not cause the current to be high enough.

Here's a crappy diagram that illustrates the scenario.

[image: Crappy diagram illustrating a ground-fault]

And here's the same crappy diagram with the fault circuit path highlighted.

[image: Crappy diagram illustrating a ground-fault with circuit highlighted]

Notice the path that flows through the ground, the resistance there will be really high. Using Mr. Ohm's formula I=E/R, you'll find that as resistance goes up, current goes down.

This is why GFCI devices were invented, and are so important. A ground-fault is typically a low current fault, though may carry enough current to kill a person.  GFCI devices open the circuit if the ground-fault current gets high enough to affect a person (4-6 milliamperes).

---

If the fault ground rod was properly connected to the other ground rod, then the breaker *should* trip. This is because the low resistance connection between the rods, provides an effective ground-fault current path. Since the effective ground-fault current path resistance will be low, the fault current should be high enough to eventually trip the breaker (if not instantaneously).

Comment: I am so close to understanding what you've just said but I must be something some thing. "  Since the ground rod has a high contact resistance with the earth, the current seen at the breaker is quite low " don't you mean HIGH. More resistance in the earth means more current to push through the earth to get to the other ground rod to get to breaker panel and back to transformer.

Comment: by the way +1 for the " crappy diagram " that was highlighted, helpful.

Comment: @MacR. No, I meant low.  `Current = Voltage / Resistance`  `120 volts / 10,000 ohms = 0.012 amperes`.

Answer (score 2):

> **why wont the breaker trip.**

Firstly, remember that a 20A breaker won't be OK at 19.9999 Amps and suddenly trip at 20.0001 Amps. A 20A breaker might pass 30A¹ for several minutes¹ (or more). It is mainly designed to protect wiring in the walls that *slowly* heats up due to overcurrent.

Secondly, soil/dirt is not a great conductor, especially when dry. It may have a high resistance that limits the fault-current.

[image]

Copper has conductivity 58,500 mS/m, Aluminium 36,900 mS/m

So the reasons are one or more of

- the current isn't high enough (measure it with a clamp meter) and
- the current hasn't been running long enough or
- the breaker is faulty (probably least likely)

---

<sup>¹ All numbers guesswork for illustrative purposes</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Because dirt isn't necessarily a good conductor of electricity.   If it was, power lines wouldn't have 3 wires, they'd have only 2 and they'd use the earth for the third wire.  Needless to say, this has been tried and doesn't work very well.

If your panel is grounded to ground rod #1, and you tie 120V to ground rod #2, all you've done is put a hazardous voltage on that ground rod.

Now if your ground is good, e.g. The same rod, then there are 2 more reasons not to get a trip.  One is that your breaker is defective.  The other is one of several defects in your wiring.  The most obvious is hot-neutral exchanged.  Obviously if you fault neutral to ground, you won't get a breaker trip.

Comment: But shouldn't the 20 amp breaker reach current over 20 amps if the hot wire was connected to grounding rod #2 (your example) because the earth would " suck " almost infinite amount of current, hence the breaker sensing the over current and then doing it's job by tripping.

Comment: The earth isn't an infinite current sink.  The PE wire is really a *bonding* wire from appliance cases back to the service entrance neutral.

Comment: By "infinite current sink" I think you just mean "good conductor".  Like I say, if the earth were that, we'd need one less wire on our transmission lines.   It's real common for two ground rods to have high impedance between them.   That's why grounds must be carried to sub-panels even when they must also have ground rods.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel alright fine, not infinite current; but wont the ground rod draw more than 20 amps current and then trip the breaker.

Comment: @Harper by impedance I take it as you meaning resistance. And I would understand that and what you are saying about the earth not being a good conductor, got it. But what I am trying to ask is WHY wouldn't the earth draw an excess of 20 amps through the rod that has it's 120 line shorted (connected) to it. Isn't the current suppose to go to ground (via rod) and spread out and disappear in the case of a short on the hot side. Atleast my understanding of the ground is that it's suppose

Comment: Understandable, it's always bandied about as the theoretical perfect conductor and reference for all voltages. Try actually getting dirt to conduct electricity, it's pretty flaky lol.  They care about earth reference because even milliamps can kill.  The concern is the user who is earthed and is shocked by a tool.  They want neutral-human-earth faults to be undangerous, so they reference neutral to earth. They solve hot-human faults in equipment design by making hot-neutral or hot-EGC far more likely.  EGC is "equipment grounding conductor" or the green wire.

Comment: @Harper the way i understood it is that grounding any piece of equipment directly to the ground near it is useless because current or overcurrent will just use the physical earth as a path back to its source and that is why it is of more importance to place a EEGC (effective equipment grounding conductor) on ANYTHING electricaly energized to provide a correct path for high current fault back to it's source. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: You lay an EGC so you have a guaranteed high-current path to assure the circuit breaker trips.  If actual earth does too, that's fine... the danger is if it *doesn't*.